# i want to use pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen but like little bit up of it not really the center

Tags: python, pyautogui

this is what i use to click on object but i wanna click like little bit up of it not really the center

```
from pyautogui import * 
import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
import win32api, win32con

while 1:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Screenshot_1.png',grayscale=True, confidence=0.5) != None:
        print("I can see it")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        cords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Screenshot_1.png',)
        pyautogui.click (cords)

    else:
            print("I am unable to see it")
            time.sleep(0.5
```

Comment: What do you mean by **i wanna click the upper of it**? Please provide more details.

Comment: like little bit up of it not really the center

Comment: I mean **edit your question accordingly**.

Answer (score 1):

When calling the `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()` method, you're storing the X and Y axis pixels in your `cords` variable. So, you could easily just, instead of storing both in one variable, unpack them:

`x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()`

Once you've unpacked them, if your goal is to click slightly above the center of the image, then just subtract a certain amount of pixels from the y axis.

`y -= 100 # It can be the amount of pixels you want`

And then click on the coordinates:
`pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(x, y)`